# CodeIgniter: HTML Email Arriving Blank

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I am trying to receive the below email with **Thunderbird** but it is arriving blank.  The from and subject* are intact but the message is blank yet the `print_debugger();` shows all the content** etc

*The subject shows the Company Name but not the 'User Registration Confirmation' text

** I am also getting the following errors on the `print_debugger();` page but I think it is caused by the `print_debugger();`

`Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by line 72 -> echo $this->email->print_debugger(); for both the session and url_helper`

**Config:**

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
$config['send_multipart'] = FALSE ;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

**Controller:**

```
function _userRegEmail($activateCode,$email,$firstname,$lastname){
        $data['companyName'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName;
        $data['companyEmail'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactEmail;
        $data['companyContact'] = $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactName;
        $data['firstName'] = $firstname;
        $data['lastName'] = $lastname;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['activateCode'] = $activateCode;

        $this->email->from($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreContactEmail, $this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName);
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName 'User Registration Confirmation');

        $messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg',$data, TRUE);

        $this->email->message($messageContent);

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

**View:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 600px;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto;font-family: Arial, &quot;MS Trebuchet&quot;, sans-serif">
        <div class="header" style="width: 100%">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;color: #00afd8"><?php echo $companyName; ?></h1>
            </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 15px">Hello <?php echo $firstName; ?></h2>
                <p style="margin-left: 15px">Thank you for signing up to Farm Ads.</p>
                <p style="margin-left: 15px">Could you please click <a href="<?php base_url(); ?>users/confirm/"<?php $activateCode; ?>>here</a> to activate your account.</p>

                <div class="from">
                    <p class="bold" style="margin-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px">Regards,</p>
                    <p style="margin-left: 15px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px"><?php $companyContact; ?></p>
                    </div>
             </div> 
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing `$data` to the view. Instead of:

```
$messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg','', TRUE);
```

Try this:

```
$messageContent= $this->load->view('email_templates/userReg', $data, TRUE);
```

In the code for the email subject line you forgot a `.` to connect the two strings:

```
$this->email->subject($this->core_model->companyDetails()->coreCompanyName.' User Registration Confirmation');
```

There is also a mistake in your view.  The `$activateCode` should be inside the quotes of `<a href="">`, not outside. And you forgot `echo` in a few places in your view.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/confirm/<?php echo $activateCode; ?>">here</a>
```

Comment: opps,  I need to update the code,  Was from a previous question.  I am  now passing the $data

Comment: I don't see any other mistakes in your code. Instead of sending the email, try displaying the email view and see what happens. If there are any errors, update your question and I may be able to help.

Comment: Maybe one more thing... you are using `base_url()` in the view. Did you load the url helper? `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: Hey,  I get the html code when I send the email as text just not HTML,  Also how would I insert a space into my subject line?

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer?? I am trying to help you... The question about the space: just add a space before `User Registration Confirmation`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I never suggested you should send the email as text... One other thing you can try is `$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';` instead of `$config['protocol'] = 'mail';`.

Comment: The space is not being followed through.  Will try sendmail

Comment: Did you put the space after the `'`? Please update your question and show me what your code looks like now.

Comment: Good answers @Mischa - Jess Did you try echo'ing just the view.have you tried the email method function Print_debugger() ?run it after the send() function.